# Google Pagespeed Insights (Lighthouse) is telling that I'm not using jquery

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, lighthouse

On the [report](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fautocustos.pt) of Google Pagespeed Insights on my website I get this suggestion:

[image]

When I use the `Coverage tab` on Chrome Dev tools, just 30% of the `jquery.min.js` file is not used

[image]

Therefore I have the following questions:

- If the file *is used*, why am I getting this suggestion? A bug?
- Am I supposed to split the jquery file in two, and load initially just the used part? I've never seen that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove unused code Google Page Speed and others errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065117/remove-unused-code-google-page-speed-and-others-errors)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62065737/2702894 I answered this exact thing a couple of days ago here bud, hope it helps!

Comment: paragraphs 2,3 and 4 are the relevant parts for you, if you need more clarity then let me know.

Comment: As for in this use case, I would ignore it unless you are prepared to rewrite the page!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie it does not fully answer my problem, because I'm talking about jquery. I will not split jquery myself. It's a file that is served in one piece. And the same with analytics?! This file is from Google.

Comment: You can split jQuery if you want, just compile from source, analytics you can download it to your server every 4 hours and then serve locally. It is achievable but as I said, I wouldn't worry about it, it is just a **suggestion** from PSI and not a set rule. As long as you defer them until the above the fold content has been rendered I wouldn't worry. (see "critical request chains" on your report, jquery is blocking your initial page render). 87 is a good score when you have a video background, the best suggestion I have is turn your video into a SVG animation to save bandwidth.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote in case you have further questions then I can put them in an answer for you.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie yes please, do create a reply, that I set it as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot.